# How to zip with password protected the multiple zipped file from a folder?

Tags: c#, zip

i'm working on the program to zip the zipped files in a folder with a password protected. For example i have multiple zipped file in a folder D:\Work\ZippedFile which is ABC.zip, CDE.zip, TZE.zip. I want to zip all the zipped file into one zip file named AllFile.zip with a password protected. What have i tried so far is as below:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\Work\ZippedFile");
foreach (string dir in dirs)
if (file.Contains(".zip"))
{
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        string filename = file.Substring(51);
        zip.Password = "Abc!23";
        zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
        zip.AddFile(file, "");
        zip.Save(dir + "\\" + "AllFile.zip");
    }
}
```

I know this will output a single zip file for each zipped file, I hope somebody can give me an idea on how to achieve the right output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't it obvious? move saving and creating new instance of ZipFile outside the loop (only AddFile should be in loop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to zip multiple files using only .net api in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243929/how-to-zip-multiple-files-using-only-net-api-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new zip file for each existing zip file. Create a single new zip file and add all the existing zip files to it.

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\Work\ZippedFile");

    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        if (file.Contains(".zip"))
        {   
            string filename = file.Substring(51);
            zip.AddFile(file, "");
        }
    }

    zip.Password = "Abc!23";
    zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
    zip.Save(dir + "\\" + "AllFile.zip");
}
```